# Trouble when writing to file

Tags: c++, io

I have a simple program. It takes `stdin` and outputs what was just inputted by the user. There's a few problems I'm having with is code:

1. For some reason, in the middle of my inputting, it stops taking input and exits the program. [The input is in bold, the following output isn't]

   [---]./a.out

   **Stephen Harper**

   Stephen Harper

   **Barack Obama**

   Barack Obama

   **Donald Trump**

   Donald Trump

   **Ben Carson**
2. If I were to put the above into a file called file1.txt and write

   ```
   ./a.out < file1.txt
   ```

, it would work, but if I put the above input into a file with say a ".in" extension and do the same thing, it won't.

3. If I change the naems in my input, it would change the number of lines of input that are accepted.

I'd appreciate it if someone told me what was happening.

Thanks

My code is:

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <fstream>
    #include <sstream>
    #include <string>

    using namespace std;

    int main() {
        bool empt = false;
        int num_ppl = 0;
        int num_spoilt = 0;
        ofstream names2 ("names2.txt");

        if (names2.is_open()) {
            int a = 0;
            while(1) {
            string line;
            getline(cin, line);
            if (line.length() == 0) {
                empt = true;
                break;
            }
            if (((line[a] >= 'A') && (line[a] <= 'Z')) || 
                ((line[a] >= 'a') && (line[a] <= 'z'))) {
                cout << line << endl;
                names2 << line;
                names2 << endl;
                num_ppl++;
            } else {
                break;
            }
            a++;    
        }
        names2.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: By the way, you could easily have found the problems if you just knew how to use a debugger. If you step through the code, line by line, in a debugger while watching the variables and their values, you would easily have found the problem yourself very quickly.

Answer (score 0):

It's the check you have that the letter is indeed a letter that fails.

Lets take it from the beginning:

1. For the input `Stephen Harper` you check that `line[0]` is a letter, which it is.
2. For the input `Barack Obama` you check that `line[1]` is a letter, which it is.
3. For the input `Donald Trump`  you check that `line[2]` is a letter, which it is.
4. For the input `Ben Carson` you check that `line[3]` is a letter, which is ***isn't***, and so you break out of the loop.

If you want to make sure that all of the input are letters (or spaces) you need to do it in a separate loop. Or use a [standard algorithm function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm) like [`std::all_of`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/all_any_none_of):

```
if (std::all_of(std::begin(line), std::end(line),
    [](const char& ch) {
        return std::isalpha(ch) || std::isspace(ch);
    }))
{
    ...
}
else
    break;
```

Comment: OK. Thank You for that. I can't believe I didn't see that. But I'm still unsure about the second problem I stated in my post. Why is that happening?